# Clustering algorithm for identifying circuits in time-stamped geolocation data

Tags: r, time-series, python, clustering, multivariate-analysis

**Context + Overall Aim:**

We have months of data tracking where a truck has travelled around a mine site, and we need to identify circuits it travels. The purpose of the truck is to essentially transport loads repeatedly from one location to another. A complete circuit is defined as where a truck is loaded, hauls to a location, dumps the load, and returns to be loaded. A cycle is then defined as a truck travelling the full circuit at least once. The truck can travel multiple circuits within a day and some of the paths may overlap.

We have manually identified 6 circuits; however, it was highly time-consuming and an unsustainable method with more data incoming. So, the challenge is to identify the circuits in a fully automated or semi-automated manner.

**Data Given:**

We have been given the following truck data with respect to time (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS) in 10 second snapshots:

- Speed (km/h)
- GPS co-ordinates (longitude and latitude in degrees)
- Total inlet fuel (L/h)
- Total return fuel (L/h)

**Assumptions:**

- For it to be defined as a circuit, it must have a minimum of X cycles (initially, X = 5)
- For it to be defined as a cluster, it must have at least 5 data points (stopping points)
- A stop location is defined when the period of 0km/h lasts greater than 30 seconds and less than 10 minutes, which are the typical loading/unloading times for this fleet in operation.

**Manual Approach:**

1. Filtered out the data for when the speed=0km/h. If this period exceeded 30 seconds but remained below 10 minutes, it was considered a significant stop. At these times, the truck is likely being loaded or unloaded. These GPS co-ordinates were then noted.
2. From one of the stops identified, the respective GPS co-ordinates were then followed manually on the map to trace out a potential circuit. This was repeated several times, with each time being a cycle, until a circuit was defined.
3. The verified circuits had their GPS co-ordinates at the first stop time (loading) and second stop time (unloading) noted in a table that could later be referred to.
4. A VLOOKUP formula was used to search the rest of the data for the manually identified start and end locations from step 3. If continuous rows of data were labelled to the same circuit, it was defined as that circuit.
5. The circuits were verified by comparing the identified cycles’ duration and distance travelled as these should be similar for each circuit.

The manual approach worked, but it’s too slow. Various hours are used to identify just one circuit, and many more are taken to validate that circuit across the whole data population.

**Automated Approach:**

The way we are currently thinking of semi-automating the identification of the mine circuits is as follows:

1. Identifying stops: Algorithm written for when the speed of the truck is speed is 0km/h for a period between 30s < X < 10minutes (typical loading and unloading times)
2. Clustering the stops: Clustering stops that are nearby in location based on the GPS data. Initially using the DBSCAN algorithm to complete this.
3. Identifying circuits: Determine correlations (such as frequency and direction) between the stop clusters to map out potential circuits. Maybe use of sequence mining algorithms.

**Automation Attempts**

I am new to clustering algorithms and I’m hitting a couple of roadblocks. For example, when utilising the ‘eps’ variable in the DBSCAN algorithm it was hard to determine an ideal variable. When set too low, too many clusters are found and it’s hard to understand the validity of them. Whereas, when set too high it seemed to create incorrect results.

I have yet to consider time and speed in the clustering algorithm as I’m not entirely sure how to include them as variables in the DBSCAN. As a result, we are currently only clustering the “stopped” state of the truck. Is there any way to analyse the whole data set to identify circuits and not just the stopping clusters? I was thinking somehow using time and speed to be able to identify trajectories between clusters.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This is more related to travel optimization as employed by linear programming models. Review the massive literature on the *traveling salesman problem* and computational complexity. Therefore, this query is more related to computer science than statistics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem